# How can I restrict a Google Scholar search to a specified set of journals?

Tags: google-scholar

As an example, suppose I want to search for articles that contain the words "class size" and appear in either *The Journal of Political Economy* or in the *American Economic Review*. When I use the advanced search, it works as expected when I search for "class size" and restrict it to *The Journal of Political Economy*
or to  *American Economic Review* individually. However, when I try to restrict the search to the union by separating with an OR or with a comma, it doesn't work. It thinks I'm looking for a journal called *The Journal of Political Economy OR American Economic Review*, for example. Does anybody know if this is possible to do, and if so, what the correct syntax is?

EDIT: So, for the case mentioned above, it seems to work just fine if I put quotes around each journal name:

```
"Journal of Political Economy " OR "American Economic Review"
```

I can do this in the advances search bar, or in the main bar at the top with the syntax mentioned in the answer below:

```
class size ("Journal of Political Economy " OR "American Economic Review")
```

However, what I didn't realize is that the problem that I was originally running into was also that the search bar seems to be cutting off the end of the search query if it's too long. For example, suppose I search among three different journals:

```
class size ("Journal of Political Economy " OR "American Economic Review" OR "Quarterly Journal of Economics ")
```

I get the following result:[image]
Am I doing something wrong here, is this a bug, or does Google Scholar simply not support doing things like this? Ideally, I'd like to limit a Google Scholar search to 5-10 journals rather than be limited to just two. Any ideas?

Comment: If we can't find an answer, is there some kind of official Google Scholar forum somewhere where I could ask this question?

Comment: I think that the last edit changed too much the question, instead of a edit a follow up question should be posted. Regarding an official Google Scholar forum, I could find a link on the Google Scholar UI nor on the about Google Scholar. You could try Google Search Help Forum -> https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/websearch

Comment: @jmbejara >>> "Am I doing something wrong here, is this a bug, or does Google Scholar simply not support doing things like this? Ideally, I'd like to limit a Google Scholar search to 5-10 journals rather than be limited to just two. Any ideas?" Its either the space or fault on google's side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the advanced search

[image: Google Scholar advanced search]

or write in the search box

```
"class size" ("The Journal of Political Economy" OR "The American Economic Review")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know if this is possible to do, and if so, what the correct syntax is?

There is no such syntax. But you can search on multiple papers by putting their name in quotation in the "any of these words" box. An example:

> class size "The Journal of Political Economy" OR "American Economic Review"

Edit: The spaces are probably breaking up the search query (or its fault on google's side). Try this:

> class size "Journal of Political Economy" OR "American Economic Review" OR "Quarterly Journal of Economics"

[image]